# How do I get the value of a <h:outputLabel> tag in JSF?

Tags: jsf

```
<h:outputLabel binding="#{prodId}"
               value="#{productManagementBean.product.id}"/>
```

I want to get the value of `#{productManagementBean.product.id}` from the output label. I have tried adding binding and trying the `.value` method but it keeps giving me `null`. I want to be able to pass in that value like this

```
<h:commandButton value="Increase"
                 action="#{productManagementBean.addOne(prodId.value)}"/>
```

Its not working because `prodId.value` is always giving me `null`. But when I visit the page in a web browser, it does show the value of `#{productManagementBean.product.id}`. How should I get the value?

Comment: How about action="#{productManagementBean.addOne(productManagementBean.product.id)}" ?

Comment: http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/resolveComponent